Use cx_Oracle on AWS Glue to insert the data to AWS Oracle RDS
I need to insert data into my AWS Oracle RDS using AWS Glue job. I want to use cx_Oracle to perform the task. I have the zip file on my S3 bucket which can be used to fetch the cx_Oracle. While I tried to import cx_Oracle on AWS Glue job, I got the following error: Error Category: IMPORT_ERROR; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'.
I have the oracle client zip file in the S3 bucket. I already provided the required S3 path in Python library path in the AWS Glue job details but still unable to import cx_Oracle.

Start by using the latest version of cx_Oracle: it was renamed to python-oracledb two years ago.

Since cx_Oracle is available at https://pypi.org/. You can add it via the Job parameters configuration using key '--additional-python-modules' and value 'cx-Oracle' or 'cx-Oracle 8.3.0', like this :  ,

Thanks for sharing the tip.  But for readers, don't use cx_Oracle because development in that namespace stopped two years ago.  Use the 'oracledb' module instead, which is the new name for the driver, see https://pypi.org/project/oracledb/
